# Tags system using "Toxi" solution CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, tags, tagging

First, i have three tables: **video, tag and tagvideo**. I already joined the three tables using left join.

My current objectives is to display list of related videos based on the current video tags. So far, i'm able to output the current video tags and trying to store in array where it will be used in the 'toxi' solution algorithm.
 Although i followed the 'toxi' solution procedure, i still encountered errors: **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**, which it points to model($this->db->where_in('tag.tag_id', $result);) and for database: **Not unique table/alias: 'video'**. 
I want to link the resulted tags with its video_id in the tagvideo table, [Tagvideo table diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jdry.jpg)

i already checked the inside of $result,an i assumed its already in array form.
By using this:`echo '<pre>'.var_export($result, true).'</pre>'; exit;`.
I follow the steps from this link: http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-display-search-results-with.html

Controller:

```
public function view($videoId) 
{
    if ($videoId == null) 
    {
        redirect ('video/index');
    }
    else {
        $videoDetails = $this->video_model->getVideoDetails($videoId);
        $relatedVideo = $this->video_model->getRelated($videoId);

        $data = array (
            'videoDetails' => $videoDetails,
            'relatedVideo' => $relatedVideo
            );

        $this->load->view('video/userdisplay' , $data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
   public function getRelated($videoId)
   {
    //output the current video tags
    $this->db->select('tag.tag_id');
    $this->db->from('video','tagmap','tag');
    $this->db->join('tagmap', 'tagmap.video_id=video.video_id','left');
    $this->db->join('tag', 'tag.tag_id=tagmap.tag_id','left');
    $this->db->where('tagmap.video_id', $videoId); 

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    { 
      $result = $query->result(); 

        //show related videos based on the tags
        $this->db->select('video.*');
        $this->db->from('video','tagmap','tag');
        $this->db->join('tagmap', 'tagmap.video_id=video.video_id','left');
        $this->db->join('tag', 'tag.tag_id=tagmap.tag_id','left');

        $tag_count = count($result);

        $this->db->where_in('tag.tag_id', $result);
        $this->db->group_by('video.video_id');

        $count = "COUNT(video.video_id) =".$tag_count;
        $this->db->having($count);
        $query2 = $this->db->get('video');
        return ($query2->num_rows() > 0)  ? $query2->result() : FALSE; 
    }
    else
    { 
      return FALSE; 
    } 


}
```

View:

```
<b>Related videos:<b>
                <?php if (!empty($relatedVideo)): ?>
                <?php foreach($relatedVideo as $item):?>
                <?php echo $item->video_topic?>
                <?php endforeach;?> 
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo "No related videos." ?>
                <?php endif; ?>enter code here
```

Comment: first you have an extra single quote here => `$this->db->from('video','tagmap','tag'');`. second why do you select from multiple tables that already exist in `join` part?

Comment: because when i removed the other two tables(video & tagmap), im unable to retrieve the current video tags which shows this error: **Not unique table/alias: 'tag'**

Comment: are these current video tags in `tag` table?

Comment: yes,this is the current video tags, where im planning to check which video_id belongs to the tags in tagvideo table   `array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'tag_id' => '1',
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'tag_id' => '3',
  )),
  2 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'tag_id' => '4',
  )),
)`